# How do I convert a CRC function from C to Ruby?

Tags: c, ruby

I am trying to convert the following C function into Ruby, and can not figure out what I am doing wrong. I have a feeling it has to do with data types, specifically when passing them into the Ruby function, but cannot pinpoint the exact error.

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint32_t btle_calc_crc(uint32_t crc_init, uint8_t *data, int len) {
    uint32_t state = crc_init;
    uint32_t lfsr_mask = 0x5a6000; // 010110100110000000000000
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        uint8_t cur = data[i];
        for (j = 0; j < 8; ++j) {
            int next_bit = (state ^ cur) & 1;
            cur >>= 1;
            state >>= 1;
            if (next_bit) {
                state |= 1 << 23;
                state ^= lfsr_mask;
            }
        }
    }  
    return state;
}
int main(){
  uint32_t crc_init = 0x55555555;
  uint8_t data[] = {0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06};
    uint32_t crc = btle_calc_crc(crc_init, data, sizeof(data));
    printf("crc: %i\n", crc);
}
```

This is my Ruby version:

```
def calculate_crc(crc_init, data)
    lfsr_mask = 0x5a6000
    state = crc_init
    data.each do |byte|
        cur = byte
        (0..7).each do |i|
            next_bit = (state ^ cur) & 1;
            cur = (cur >> 1) && 0xff  # only 8 bit
            state = state >> 1
            if(next_bit == 1) 
                state = state | 1 << 23
                state = state ^ lfsr_mask
            end
        end
    end
    return(state)
end
crc = calculate_crc(0x555555, [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06])
puts "crc: #{crc}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using different values for your `crc_init`; the C version is `0x55555555` (8 5's) and the Ruby version is `0x555555` (6 5's). You should correct this first.

Also, I suspect you need to use `&` rather than `&&` on this line:

```
cur = (cur >> 1) && 0xff  # only 8 bit
```

Answer (score 2):

Calculating CRC in Ruby is much easier than that:

```
require 'zlib'
crc32 = Zlib.crc32('your message')
```

EDIT:

Or you can write the C extension to Ruby using "[How to create a Ruby extension in C in under 5 minutes](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-under-5-minutes-100.html)" or "[How to create a Ruby extension in C in 43 seconds](http://www.rubyinside.com/how-to-create-a-ruby-extension-in-c-in-43-seconds-167.html)". The first way is more universal and propably will be faster.

Comment: it is not a typical crc, so - i dont believe that would work.